# Move arrow to each menu when its selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of three items like

```
<ul id="tab_sel35116">
 <li><a href="#description35116" class="job_content" data-id="35116">Description</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#msg_body35116" class="job_content select_tab" data-id="35116">Messages</a></li>
 <li><a class="job_content" data-id="35116">Applicants</a></li>
 <div id="down_blue_arr"><span class="about_down_arrow" style="left: 20px;"></span><span class="about_down_arrow1" style="left: 20px;"></span></div>
</ul>
```

In this i want is when i will select any item of the list then the arrow will be under the menu. The arrow div is `down_blue_arr`

Here is the CSS

```
.about_down_arrow{position:absolute;border-color: #4793D8 transparent transparent transparent; border-width:9px;border-style:solid;width:0;height:0;float:right;top:25px;left:20px;}
.about_down_arrow1{position:absolute;border-color: #F7F7F7 transparent transparent transparent ; border-width:9px;border-style:solid;width:0;height:0;float:right;top:23px;left:20px;}
```

How to do it in Jquery any idea guys ??

Comment: can you post your jsfiddle?

Comment: i cant see any arrow in your code. post some more code or update in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/y3A8s/

Comment: @RIA Dev What do you mean by "under the menu"??

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore http://jsfiddle.net/himansuparichha/y3A8s/1/ this is the fiidle...the arrow should move to the selected field

Comment: r u looking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/u5nsd/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai yes something like that but please refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/himansuparichha/y3A8s/1/

Comment: @RIA Dev Here, I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3A8s/6/)

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore If you post as the answer then i can able to accept

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Any way u know u r right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3A8s/6/).
I've added the following JS code to it -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tab_sel35116 li a").on("click", moveArrow);
});

function moveArrow() {
    var pos = $(this).position().left;
    $("#down_blue_arr").css("left", pos + "px");
}
```

and updated a bit of css too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all move your arrow in li and hide them by default. then show arrow with an active class. you actually have to change your markup like this.  **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3A8s/7/)**

**HTML**

```
    <div id='tabs' class='job_min_tab' style='float:right;position:relative'>
        <ul id="tab_sel35116">
            <li class='active'><a href="#description35116" class="job_content" data-id="35116">Description</a>

    <span class="down_arrow1" style="left: 20px;"></span>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#msg_body35116" class="job_content select_tab" data-id="35116">Messages</a>

    <span class="down_arrow1" style="left: 20px;"></span>

            </li>
            <li><a class="job_content" data-id="35116">Applicants</a>

    <span class="down_arrow1" style="left: 20px;"></span>

            </li>
            <div id="down_blue_arr"></div>
        </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .down_arrow {
    position:absolute;
    border-color: #4793D8 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width:9px;
    border-style:solid;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    float:right;
    top:14px;
    left:20px; display:none;
}
.down_arrow1 {
    position:absolute;
    border-color: #f7f7f7 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width:9px;
    border-style:solid;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    float:right;
    top:13px;
    left:20px;
    display:none;
}
li.active .down_arrow1, li.active .down_arrow  {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I think you should see this             fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/himansuparichha/y3A8s/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vth5g/1/

Code:

Html:

```
<ul id="tab_sel35116">
 <li id="item1" onclick="itemClicked(this)"><a href="#description35116" class="job_content" data-id="35116">Description</a></li> 
 <li id="item2" onclick="itemClicked(this)"><a href="#msg_body35116" class="job_content select_tab" data-id="35116">Messages</a></li>
 <li id="item3" onclick="itemClicked(this)"><a class="job_content" data-id="35116">Applicants</a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.about_down_arrow{position:absolute;border-color: #4793D8 transparent transparent transparent; border-width:9px;border-style:solid;width:0;height:0;float:right;left:20px;}
.about_down_arrow1{position:absolute;border-color: #F7F7F7 transparent transparent transparent ; border-width:9px;border-style:solid;width:0;height:0;float:right;left:20px;}
```

JS:

```
function itemClicked(liObj)
{
 $("#down_blue_arr").remove();

    $(liObj).before('<div id="down_blue_arr"><span class="about_down_arrow" style="left: 20px;"></span><span class="about_down_arrow1" style="left: 20px;"></span></div>');  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/y3A8s/4/). You have u put `:hover` on li and put each arrow inside li and make li relative